# How to mimic scrolling with Apache's HttpClient library?

Tags: java, javascript, scroll, apache-commons-httpclient

Some webpage feature a limited amount of content to start with and only show more when scrolling, for example https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index?sid=396545161&tab=popular&filter=lang&sort=popular

For humans, this does not pose a problem. However, when attempting to process this data automatically with Apache's HttpClient library, this does pose a problem. How can one ask HttpClient to fetch more topics on this Yahoo Answers page?

Closer inspection of the javascript on the page shows subsequent calls to

```
[GET] https://answers.yahoo.com/xhr-cat-popular.php?filter=lang&sort=popular&ct=1408831552&cl=1408831552&offset=21&categoryId=396545161&page=2&_txnid=1408831555799&crumb=TVGhgfkE0db
[GET] https://answers.yahoo.com/xhr-cat-popular.php?filter=lang&sort=popular&ct=1408831552&cl=1408831552&offset=41&categoryId=396545161&page=3&_txnid=1408831557894&crumb=TVGhgfkE0db
[GET] https://answers.yahoo.com/xhr-cat-popular.php?filter=lang&sort=popular&ct=1408831552&cl=1408831552&offset=61&categoryId=396545161&page=4&_txnid=1408831823937&crumb=TVGhgfkE0db
[GET] https://answers.yahoo.com/xhr-cat-popular.php?filter=lang&sort=popular&ct=1408831552&cl=1408831552&offset=81&categoryId=396545161&page=5&_txnid=1408831827678&crumb=TVGhgfkE0db
```

etc. when scrolling, which provides the desired contents for the subsequent pages. However, when opening these links in my browser window (or in HttpClient for that matter) I am simply redirected to the home page. Am I missing something, or how should I trick the server into thinking I'm just the javascript asking for the next page contents?

Answer (score 0):

You can't (at least not in a way that would function everywhere). That functionality uses Javascript, and HttpClient doesn't understand Javascript.

You could go through the page source and determine if there's a way to fetch more content, but it can be tricky (minified javascript or other similar obstacles).

Comment: @user1111929 Instead of looking through JavaScript, you can open up the developer tools and look at the request that's fetching the extra content and make that call yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but for some strange reason I still didn't get it to work properly. I updated the question to reflect my progress.